# How to overcome if ios application has no unique accessibility id's and developers are not ready to provide is there any solution?

Tags: appium-ios

Anyone please guide me right now i am facing this issue my ios development is busy with other work so they are not ready to provide unique accessibility ids.I discussed with team they are telling we have to change bunch of code with this time it's not possible then how to overcome this problem is there any alternatives.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try to write the dynamic xpath.The link is useful"http://learn-automation.com/how-to-write-dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/"

Comment: Hi sneha that is for selenium web application i wanted to know for Appium especially IOS app

Comment: Hi Manish, Sneha is correct. Use XPATH in iOS automation for unique ID. The links has selenium one, however use the xpath concept in iOS. e.g.  //XCUIElementTypeNavigationBar/XCUIElementTypeButton . The Appium inspector provides the XPATH of selected element, here is the link for desktop client of APPIUM https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.6.3 .

Comment: Hi Arul Yes i was using appium inspector only but problem is i'm automating trading app so all values daily changing could you please see below element for appium inspector example generally developers provide unique Id's i'm looking is there alternative we can't write xpath these type of elements                                 
 Ex: accessibility id 945,669.00 MYR :    Xpath://XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name="945,669.00 MYR"] .          Type: XCUIElementTypeStaticText : Value,Name,Label=945,669.00 MYR

Comment: Use Dynamic xpath concept.In your case the value is going to change every time.So you have to use xpath using contains method.e.g://XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@name,'MYR')]